# Как изменить текст в многих *.docx файлах исходя из имени файла?

Tags: php, docx

- Есть 1000 шт. файлов MS WORD с расширением **.docx**
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Имя каждого файла - это цифры по порядку от **1568** до **2568**.
- В каждом файле нужно поменять цифру **15** на имя файла без расширения файла.
- Есть скрипт на PHP который это делает это для файлов **.txt** и **.html** и прочих файлов, которые редактируются "блокнотом". Но этот скрипт не меняет текст внутри **.docx** файлов и "калечит" эти **.docx** файлы.

**Что не так в PHP скрипте?**

```html
<?php

     
for ($i=1568; $i  < 1593; $i++) {                    //  диапазон  имен файлов которые читать нужно
    $file = file_get_contents("C:/1/{$i}.docx");     //  C:/1/ в папку 1 нужно скинуть файлы в которые нужно поменять текст на имя файлов
    $nextfile = str_replace('15', $i, $file); 
    file_put_contents("C:/1/{$i}.docx", $nextfile); //сохраняем
}

?>
```

Comment: `docx` это особый формат файла и в нем нельзя взять и поменять одно значение на другое через `str_replace`. Для того чтобы работать с `docx` в php используется либа [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

Comment: @u_mulder docx - это несколько xml-файлов, просто за-zip-пованные. Там нужен архиватор ZIP и SAX-парсер